# Testing a custom UseInterval hook with jest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, jestjs, react-testing-library

My hook is;

```
function useInterval() {
  const ref: MutableRefObject<NodeJS.Timer | null > = useRef(null);
  function set(callback: () => void, delay: number) {
    ref.current = setInterval(callback, delay)
  }
  function clear() {
    if (ref.current) {
      clearInterval(ref.current)
      ref.current = null
    }
  }
  return { set, clear }
}
```

My test is;

```
it("set: This should be called 10 times", () => {
    var callback = jest.fn();
    jest.useFakeTimers()
    const { result } = renderHook(() => hooks.useInterval())
    act(() => {
        result.current.set(() => { callback }, 100)    
        jest.advanceTimersByTime(1000);
    })
    expect(callback).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(10);
    jest.useRealTimers()
})
```

`renderHook()` and `act()` come from `"@testing-library/react-hooks": "^7.0.2"`

The result I keep getting is `0` from my `expect()` call. I can't seem to figure out why.

If I just use `setInterval()` `expect()` gets the correct value

```
it("setInterval", () => {
    var callback = jest.fn();
    jest.useFakeTimers()
    setInterval(callback, 100)
    jest.advanceTimersByTime(1000);
    expect(callback).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(10);
    jest.useRealTimers()
})
```

I have tried reordering the lines in every possible logical way I can think of.

I have noticed that I get the same result with or without `act()`, strangely.

Adding `timers: "fake"` or any of its variations(modern/legacy) to `jest.config.ts` doesn't seem to have any effect.

Obviously, `testing-library/react-hooks` is somehow masking `setInterval()` from `jest.useFakeTimers()` somehow but I don't understand how and am therefore unable to achieve the result I am looking for.

A part of me thinks that my hook isn't being hit by `jest.useFakeTimers()` because the fake timers are not being globally replaced, but I don't know how to do this.

Also, I'm using Typescript. Not that I think that makes a difference.

Comment: That didn't work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You passed an anonymous function to the `set` method instead of the mock `callback`. So the macro-task queued by `setInterval` will call the anonymous function. That's why the assertion fails. Nothing to Jest Config, TypeScript.

e.g.

`useInterval.ts`:

```
import { MutableRefObject, useRef } from 'react';

export function useInterval() {
  const ref: MutableRefObject<ReturnType<typeof setInterval> | null> = useRef(null);
  function set(callback: () => void, delay: number) {
    ref.current = setInterval(callback, delay);
  }
  function clear() {
    if (ref.current) {
      clearInterval(ref.current);
      ref.current = null;
    }
  }
  return { set, clear };
}
```

`useInterval.test.ts`:

```
import { renderHook } from '@testing-library/react-hooks';
import { useInterval } from './useInterval';

describe('70276930', () => {
  beforeAll(() => {
    jest.useFakeTimers();
  });
  afterAll(() => {
    jest.useRealTimers();
  });
  test('should call callback interval', () => {
    const callback = jest.fn();
    const { result } = renderHook(useInterval);
    result.current.set(callback, 100);
    jest.advanceTimersByTime(1000);
    expect(callback).toBeCalledTimes(10);
  });

  test('should clear interval', () => {
    const callback = jest.fn();
    const { result } = renderHook(useInterval);
    result.current.set(callback, 100);
    jest.advanceTimersByTime(100);
    expect(callback).toBeCalledTimes(1);
    result.current.clear();
    jest.advanceTimersByTime(100);
    expect(callback).toBeCalledTimes(1);
  });
});
```

test result:

```sh
 PASS  examples/70276930/useInterval.test.ts (7.541 s)
  70276930
    ✓ should call callback interval (16 ms)
    ✓ should clear interval (1 ms)

----------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File            | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
----------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files       |     100 |       50 |     100 |     100 |                   
 useInterval.ts |     100 |       50 |     100 |     100 | 9                 
----------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       2 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        8.294 s, estimated 9 s
```

package versions:

```json
"react": "^16.14.0",
"@testing-library/react": "^11.2.2",
"jest": "^26.6.3",
```